# Refactoring this code to make better use of the CSharpFunctionalExtensions Library

Tags: c#, functional-programming, csharpfunctionalextensions

I have the following method using the [CSharpFunctionalExtensions library](https://github.com/vkhorikov/CSharpFunctionalExtensions) by [Vladimir Khorikov](https://twitter.com/vkhorikov):

```cs
public static Result<SomeObject> Create(string value) =>
    value.Length > 10
        ? Result.Fail<SomeObject>($"{nameof(value)} must be less than 10 characters long.")
        : int.TryParse(value, out int result)
            ? Result.Ok(new SomeObject(result))
            : Result.Fail<SomeObject>($"{nameof(value)} must be a number.");
```

It does what I want, but I'm not pleased with my implementation. It doesn't feel like I'm making best use of the library and its capabilities - but despite my research I'm unable to wrap my head around a better way.  I feel like I should be wrapping the validation calls in `Result.OnSuccess()` somehow but those don't return a `Result`, they return `bool` values.

I'm trying to do something like this pseudocode:

```cs
public static Result<SomeObject> Create(string value) =>
    Result
      .Is(
         () => !(value.Length > 10, // success criteria
         value, // success value
         $"{nameof(value)} must be less than 10 characters long." // Result.Fail
     ).Is( 
          () => int.TryParse(value, out int result),
          result, // changing the success value to an int
          $"{nameof(value)} must be a number."
     );
```

I'm pretty sure the library already supports what I'm trying to do, but I'm struggling with the "how".  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using ensure and map.  Like this

```cs
public static Result<SomeObject> Create(string value)
{
    int result = 0;

    return Result.Ok()
        .Ensure(() => value.Length <= 10,
                errorMessage: $"{nameof(value)} must be less than 10 characters long.")
        .Ensure(() => int.TryParse(value, out result),
                errorMessage: $"{nameof(value)} must be a number.")
        .Map(() => new SomeObject(result));
}
```

Ensure has 2 arguments here.  The first is a `Func<bool>`.  If when the Func is invoked it returns false then a failed result is returned with the error taking the value of the second argument,`errorMessage`.

Map behaves just like OnSuccess, I believe it would be fair to say you can think of it as being short hand for OnSuccessThenMapTo.  If the criteria in both of the above 2 ensures is met then an Ok result is returned and the map populates it with the newed up SomeObject object.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to return multiple error messages when multiple ensure conditions fail?

Comment: @RikD Yes, it's hard to give an example in a comment but you would probably need to use Result.Combine.  You would return say Result.Combine(",", result1, result2, ...).  The first param is whatever you want to separate the errors.  It also accepts an array of results.